# Change coding standard for CodeSniffer in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, phpcodesniffer

I've installed the CodeSniffer and want to use it with PhpStorm.

I want to use the `PSR2` coding standard to check for my source code, but it looks like the IDE checks with another standard. I can't find an option for changing the standards to define an extra parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the coding standard in Preferences->Inspections->PHP->PHP Code Sniffer validation. There is a selectbox with predefined standards like PEAR, PSR1, PSR2 and you can also define your own.

[image: codesniffer option in phpstorm]